# Can't use Azure TableStorageMembershipProvider from console application (and mstest)

Tags: azure, asp.net-membership

In a web app I'm building I'm using the TableStorageMembershipProvider sample code (downloaded from [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=windowsazuresamples&DownloadId=8221)) for user management.  I've setup the web.config correctly and everything works just fine.

I now want to write some tests, so I create a test project, reference the TableStorageMembershipProvider dll, copy the relevant sections from web.config to app.config and write one simple test.  Problem is that the first time I hit the membership code, it throws the following error:

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.AspProviders.TableStorageMembershipProvider' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

It's trying to load the TableStorageMembershipProvider from System.Web...

So I then create two separate projects - a console app and a new MVC3 web app - both of which simply reference the TableStorageMembershipProvider dll.  I setup the web.config and app.config with the same  entries which specify the membership provider and write one line of code:

```
Membership.ApplicationName = "test";
```

The MVC app works, the console app throws the same error as above.

I've tried duplicating all web app references in the console app and setting all to Copy Local = true - no luck.  Tearing my bloody hair out over this...

VS2010, all projects target .Net 4

There's got to be a real simple solution?

Comment: Yes, I'd check vtortola's suggestions. Anyway, the TableStorageMembershipProvider is a "sample", (not fully tested, no perf test, etc). If I were you, I'd inspect the code and make sure it works well in your environment and for your requirements. We ran into some weird issues with the first versions of these. Also, take into account Windows Azure storage charges for storage (rather cheap) AND transactions. If your app interacts with Membership/Profile a lot, you might end up paying more than say a SQL based Membership database. Do the math for your app.

Answer (score 1):

By default console apps don't have a reference to `System.Web`, MVC apps do.  I think you'll find that the error message you're getting is a little misleading.  What I think is happening is that `TableStorageMembershipProvider` has a dependency on `System.Web` that for whatever reason isn't flowing through to your console app.

Trying adding a reference to `System.Web` to your console app and that should fix it.

Comment: I think there probably is some dependency which is missing from the console app, but it's not System.Web.  I've added this and set Copy Local true (and done the same for all the web app referenced assemblies) - no change...

Comment: Looking at the other references in the samples and what the TableStorageMembershipProvider class inherits from, that is likely to be System.Web.Security namespace which is in the System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. Are you using ".NET 4 Framework" or
   ".NET 4 Framework Client Profile" in
   your Console application? It should
   be the first.
2. Have you the Azure assemblies in you
   path?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but all projects targeting .NET 4 (not Client Profile) and I do have the Azure assemblies in my path

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your config is set to load the class from System.Web rather than the assembly that your class is in. Can you post the config (if you're still having this problem) from your console app?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I never got this resolved and moved on to implement a different solution instead, so I no longer have this config available.